# unix command to select file using delimiter "--"

Tags: unix

```
sample1 presentation -- www.test0.com
command line input -- www.test1.com
...
```

In unix, which command I can use to only select the second half using delimiter " -- ". I tried 'cut' command, but cut -d only take one char delimiter. so ' -- ' won't work since it has 4 chars.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *many* tools to do this, here is an example in awk:

```
awk -F"--" '{ print $2 }' <infilename>
```

`-F` allows you to specify a delimiter to split each line on, `$2` is the second element of that line when it is split by `--`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/^.*-- \(.*\)/\1/' filename
```

will get you the field after `--` in all lines of `filename`.

Comment: Seems easier to do `sed -e 's/.*-- //'`